# When Android relaunches the app after being killed in background

Tags: android, android-activity

Of late I have been into an issue which has been really difficult to sort out.

I have an Activity A which has a view pager with fragments. I am loading data from server and feeding into the views. The data received from server is stored in a singleton class which can be accessed across the application. Now user moves to another activiy B which uses the server data through singleton class.

Now when user presses home and launches variety of application, my app gets killed in background. When I relaunch the application, OS try to load activity B again with its saved state(I am not doing anything in onSaveInstance), but the data in singleton class is already lost and app crashes. The thing is I cannot get the server data again in this activity. Should I save the entire data in onSaveInstance of this activity? Is it not encouraged to use singleton class to store all your data?

What is the ideal way to handle situation like this?Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can Save the data in SQLite Database and get the data from there for particular record

Answer (score 0):

How sensitive is the data? In Android is is not recommended to use a skeleton to move your data around(Passing it through intent? Static(please say no)). Ether way was commented you should probably store the data to main memory. Android provides a few options besides actually writing it to a file. Depending on how much data and its structure there are a few options.

1. [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) & [ContentResolver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html), [Basic Overview](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/content-resolvers-and-content-providers.html). I would not recommend this unless you plan on making the data accessible to other applications.
2. [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html). Good if you have preexisting sql knowledge or large amounts of data where a relation db is needed.
3. [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). As its name implies is generally used for storing user presence data, but it can also be used to store any data. I would not recommended it where there is a lot or complex data is needed to be stored.
4. [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html). Good old java file classes, no explanation needed.

With our data I would recommend creating a DataStore managing class which handles the io to any of the above methods, so when referencing the data you simply pull from that class.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such situations, you should relate to these:

- [App crashes when restoring from background after a long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964411/app-crashes-when-restoring-from-background-after-a-long-time)
- http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/