# How to persists huge data when we resume an appication in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I have read some documentations also but still I am not clear so I am asking the question here, i.e. I have an activity and Fragment I have a huge data to display in these activity and fragment. When I hit home button it'll be paused but when I reload the app from the recent list the app crashes. I don't have small amount of data to store in bundle. and in onRestoreInstanceState() method to fetch that back. So I am little confused in this can anybody help me to solve these issue. I found similar questions
[App crashes when restoring from background after a long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964411/app-crashes-when-restoring-from-background-after-a-long-time)

but this is not solved my issue.

Thanks

Comment: you can you to store raw data in SharedPreferences and then can parse the data when needed!

Comment: What type of data aand approx how much of it are you planning to presist?

Comment: I thought to do that but sharedPreferences is basically used with small data right. I have an Arraylist and other objects.

Comment: *This is an old question* posted 6 mins ago - It's not that old ;-)

Comment: @Venom its a list of custom objects and some Boolean values and other objects.

Comment: @Tim Castelijns :) yes its not

Comment: I don't exactly know your use case, but if that's a lot of structured data that you are planning to persist, maybe you should go with sqlite, and use a loader to fetch this on activity start.

Comment: If you are dealing with forms/custom views, maybe this could help you figure out a solution - http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/09/25/deep-dive-into-android-state-restoration/

Comment: @Venom ok.. for example you have a list and detail screen you are showing the detail screen based on the item selected in a list now you will hit home btn. So the app will be in pause state. Now you will use other apps and and android initiated GC and you lost data now when you try to open your first application the data is gone because of GC and the selected item is null and you will get Nullpointer exception. This is one use case.

Comment: Okay! and is this list static? or does a user can add an entry into this list, which you need to append to the existing one?

Comment: @Venom Its a static list fetched from DB.