# Activity gets close automatically when its comes back from background

Tags: android, android-activity

In my application my activity automatically gets close when I come back from background and it always shows previous activity. Example: I start app with Activity A > then goes to activity B> then activity C now I put my app in background and come and then I comeback to foreground the C activity automatically gets close it shows activity B. please help me its a big project I am working on existing code. I don't know what property has been set there. I have checked onPause() and onResume() methods everywhere in the app nothing is there that can close the activity.

```
public class EnterOtpActivity extends ChoosePhotoBaseActivity {
private ActivityEnterOtpBinding mBinding;
private EnterOtpModel model;
private String name;
private String prefix;
private String phone;
private String password;
private int spinnerPos;
private UserApi.FacebookLoginDetails fbLoginDetails = null;

@NonNull
@Override
protected Map<ImageView, Transformation<Bitmap>> getImageViewsMap() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void handleLoadedFile(@NonNull File imageTempFile) {
    imageCropped(Uri.fromFile(imageTempFile));
}

public void imageCropped(@NonNull Uri croppedImageUri) {
    model.mEditAvatarUri = croppedImageUri;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_enter_otp);
    mBinding.setModel(model = new EnterOtpModel(this, mBinding));
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        if (bundle.containsKey(BundleKeyUtils.REGISTRATION)) {
            UserDetailsForOTPVo userDetailsForOTPVo = (UserDetailsForOTPVo) bundle.getSerializable(BundleKeyUtils.REGISTRATION);
            name = userDetailsForOTPVo.getName();
            prefix = userDetailsForOTPVo.getPrefix();
            phone = userDetailsForOTPVo.getContactNumber();
            password = userDetailsForOTPVo.getPassword();
            spinnerPos = userDetailsForOTPVo.getSpinnerPosition();
            model.setContactNumber(prefix, phone);
        } else if (bundle.containsKey(BundleKeyUtils.FB_REGISTRATION)) {
            fbLoginDetails = (UserApi.FacebookLoginDetails) bundle.getSerializable(BundleKeyUtils.FB_REGISTRATION);
            prefix = fbLoginDetails.getPhone_country_code();
            phone = fbLoginDetails.getPhone();
        }
    }
    mBinding.editOtp.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(4)});
    model.setTimer();
    setContinueAction();
    otpTextWatcher();
    setOnOtpRequest();
    File f = new File(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), "temp");
    Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    model.mEditAvatarUri = imageUri;

    mBinding.textContinue.setEnabled(false);
}

private void setOnOtpRequest() {
    mBinding.textOTp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showOTPDialog();
        }
    });
}

private void setContinueAction() {
    mBinding.textContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mBinding.textContinue.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mBinding.progressContinue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mBinding.imgvArrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (fbLoginDetails == null) {
                model.onContinueAction(prefix, phone, password, name, mBinding.editOtp.getText().toString(), spinnerPos);
            }else {
                //TODO FB web call
                fbLoginDetails.setOTP_code(mBinding.editOtp.getText().toString());
                model.onFbLoginAction(fbLoginDetails, () -> {
                    mBinding.textContinue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mBinding.progressContinue.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);});
            }
        }
    });
}


public void otpTextWatcher() {
    mBinding.editOtp.addTextChangedListener(new SimpleTextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(@NonNull String newText) {
            super.onTextChanged(newText);
            if (newText.length() == 4) {
                mBinding.textContinue.setEnabled(true);
                mBinding.textContinue.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background_selector);
            }else {
                mBinding.textContinue.setEnabled(false);
                mBinding.textContinue.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_rounded_button_light_orange);
            }
        }
    });
}

public void showOTPDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(EnterOtpActivity.this,
            R.style.DialogDark));
    String meddleD = getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_msg_sms_middle);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_msg_sms_will_be) +" "+ prefix + phone +meddleD+getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_is_this_number_correct));
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.fragment_contacts_invite_sms_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            mBinding.textOTp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mBinding.progressLogIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mBinding.editOtp.setText("");
            model.reSendOtpRequest();
        }
    });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(R.string.edit, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });
    alertDialogBuilder.show();
}

//disable back button

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do nothing
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
```

}

Comment: Please add some codes

Comment: its a big project I think code will not help.

Comment: give us logcat information and add some code to help you

Comment: @Pradeep Please give the portion of the code in activity C which you think has the potential "loose ends"

Comment: @Debojyoti I have edited my code please see now it is activity C.

Comment: @PradeepDeshmukh It's safe to say that the finish() function is being called upon coming back from background.So the C activity stops

Comment: @Debojyoti  but there is no finish() function called in onResume() method.

Comment: @PradeepDeshmukh As the C activity is stopping and the previous activity is starting,maybe the function is called.Can you comment the finish() method and see?

Comment: @Debojyoti In c activity I have not called the finish() function. I think it may be happens due to the addflags() like clear top and clear task. isn't it?

Comment: @PradeepDeshmukh Please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964411/app-crashes-when-restoring-from-background-after-a-long-time.Maybe some singleton class is being collected by the garbage collector

Comment: @Debojyoti in my log cat the app is not giving any error and all.

Comment: @Debojyoti I got the problem see my answer.

Comment: @PradeepDeshmukh took you all night :) anyways congratulations

Comment: @Debojyoti yeah! 4hrs :D and Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I got the culprit in my code, actually in previous implementation they have added noHostory="true" in Manifests.xml for that activity that's why it was closing.